# How to specify fonts with special characters in CSS

Tags: css, javafx, fonts

I am trying to use the Aganè font in my javafx application, but I'm having problems in eclipse trying to get the application to utilize them.

If I use the below code, eclipse returns WARNING: Illegal character in path at index 13: fonts/Agane¦Ç 45 (light)

For what it's worth I have eclipse text file encoding set to UTF-8.

How do I use the Aganè font correctly in my css?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Aganè;
    src: url('fonts/Agane¦Ç 45 (light).ttf')
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Aganè;
    src: url('fonts/Agane¦Ç 45 (roman).ttf')
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Aganè;
    src: url('fonts/Agane¦Ç 45 (Bold).ttf')
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Aganè;
    src: url('fonts/Agane¦Ç 45 (Extra Bold).ttf')
}
```

Comment: Try to change the name of font file and place them in relevant font folder. Change the font name in above linked file. Thanks

Comment: I've tried that but when I try to change the font family name inside the ttf and generate the font using FontForge I get errors which I generated anyway but still the application does not recognize those fonts.

Comment: @shepherd7 Following VSM's advice, try dumbing-down the link to the font: `fonts/Agane-45-Extra-Bold.ttf`. It might also be a good idea to remove the _accent à grave_ from the font-family name. You can see it has been flagged in this SO example.

Comment: Renaming the ttf is not a problem, but I can't change the font family name successfully.  I tried using FontForge to do it but ran into errors when trying to generate the font with new names.  Not my forte for sure.  Not sure what you mean by 'SO example'?

Comment: @gshepherd7, https://transfonter.org/
use above link to generate ttf file.Let me know whether still there is a error.

Comment: Okay, so I uploaded the 4 Agane ttf files and converted them, but it still tells me to use Agane` as the font family name, which for some reason eclipse does not like. It tells me no viable alternative character '`'. If I try putting single quotes around it I get invalid font name.

Comment: So got it working. Eclipse complains saying invalid font family name when putting Agane in single quotes, but it still runs successfully.  I renamed the ttf files to eliminate the special character and then in my css I needed 'Agane`' 
 Thanks for all the help.